# SQL Empty query results

Tags: sql, database, select

Imagine I have a table like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE marcas
(
  id_marca integer,
  marca character varying
));
```

I would like to make a query but get the value in every field empty.

I know that could solve it like this:

`SELECT '' as id, '' as marca FROM marcas`

The problem is that i have plenty of tables and some of them have more than 100 fields...
I need a SQL statement that could get all the row fields of a table but empty and in an easy way...

Comment: what sql implementation are you using?  MSSQL, Postgres, etc.

Comment: What is that you really need? The tables structure? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method to get `NULL` in every column.  It uses `left outer join` with a failing condition:

```
select t.*
from (select 1 as val
     ) v left outer join
     table t
     on 1 = 0;
```

EDIT:

If you want to do this in Access, that is a challenge.  The expression `select 1 as val` doesn't work.  The following should:

```
select t.*
from (select max(1) as val
      from table as t 
     ) as v left outer join
     table as t
     on val = 0;
```

This should also work in Postgres, but it has unnecessary overhead.

Comment: +1 I think this is pretty much as close as you can get.

Comment: This query worked perfectly on PostgreSQL but gets an error when trying to execute it in Microsoft Access, it says that 1 = 0 expression is not admitted.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your answer. I opened a new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760573/ms-access-query looking for a specific solution on this question in ms-access. Your solution for access in my case is not working...although it works again in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
SELECT * FROM MARCAS
```

you will get a result set of

===================

ID_MARCA  |  MARCA

===================

This will return zero results but it will show all the columns in the table queried. I can't fully understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the column list and no rows returned then

```
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM marcas
```