# SELECT query to return a row from a table with all values set to Null

Tags: sql, ms-access, expression, left-join

I need to make a query but get the value in every field empty. Gordon Linoff give me the clue to this need here:
[SQL Empty query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740036/sql-empty-query-results/23740215#23740215)
which is:

```
select t.*
from (select 1 as val
     ) v left outer join
     table t
     on 1 = 0;
```

This query wors perfectly on PostgreSQL but gets an error when trying to execute it in Microsoft Access, it says that 1 = 0 expression is not admitted. How could it be fixed to work on microsoft access?

Regards,

Comment: does `select t.* from table t where 1=0` give you what you're looking for?

Comment: @nullrevolution No, that is not what he wants. The query that he has is correct and works with PostgreSQL and T-SQL, but doesn't work on Access SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table has a numeric primary key column whose values are non-negative then the following query will work in Access. The primary key field is [ID].

```sql
SELECT t2.*
FROM
    myTable AS t2
    RIGHT JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 (ID * -1) AS badID 
        FROM myTable AS t1
    ) AS rowStubs
        ON t2.ID = rowStubs.badID
```

This was tested with Access 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I am offering this answer here, even though you didn't think it worked in my edit to your original question.  What is the problem?

```
select t.*
from (select max(col) as maxval from table as t
     ) as v left join
     table as t
     on v.val < t.col;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Access doesn't like `... join ... on val = 0`. It says "JOIN expression not supported."

Comment: @GordThompson . . . I just think that Access *should* support this method.  I added a subquery, but you could really use any column and any value that is not equal.

Comment: Access seems to have an "interesting" way of handling outer JOINs when one side of the ON condition is a constant. Now your query returns the same results as `SELECT * FROM table`.

Comment: @GordThompson . . . That was a typo, it should have been `0 as val` in the subquery.  But as I say, you don't have to use a new column, you can use an existing one.

Comment: Now your query returns 0 rows. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query, but it would still need a little "manual coding".

**EDITS**:

1. Actually, you do not need the SWITCH function. Modified query below.
2. Removed the reference to Description column from one line. Still, you would need to use a Text column name (such as Description) in the last line of the query.

For example, the following query would work for the Months table:

```
select Months.*
from Months
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(select "" as DummyColumn from Months) Blank_Data
ON Months.Description = Blank_Data.DummyColumn; --hardcoded Description column
```